# Is it possible to use Google Cloud Storage daily back up with Digital Ocean Spaces (S3 compatible)?

Tags: google-cloud-storage

The sync tool takes an `s3://` format address - should this work with Digital Ocean?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the more appropriate way to achieve this sync task would be the usage of the [transfer tool](https://cloud.google.com/storage-transfer-service/) provided by Google Cloud Platform, but instead of configuring the URL for spaces, you [can create a job](https://cloud.google.com/storage-transfer/docs/create-manage-transfer-console) and specify that your transfer will be done using a [URL List](https://cloud.google.com/storage-transfer/docs/create-url-list)(via Cloud Console or Storage Transfer API)

If you have a lot of objects in your Spaces buckets, you could use the [Spaces API for list bucket's content](https://developers.digitalocean.com/documentation/spaces/#list-bucket-contents) and if you prefer, use the outcome of this API to then create a transfer job using the [Storage transfer API](https://cloud.google.com/storage-transfer/docs/reference/rest/v1/transferJobs/create) (you can take a look to the transfer spec [here](https://cloud.google.com/storage-transfer/docs/reference/rest/v1/TransferSpec)